# How can I close this message that looks like dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, system, broadcast, battery

[image]

I've uploaded an image for your reference. (Korean android screen)

The example image is a low-battery warning image
but what I want to remove is the battery temperature warning message.

I'd like to use the java code to detect that message and close it.

Comment: That is shown by your system launcher, so you can't remove that.

Comment: Can't I close it with any code?

Comment: No, you can't do anything about that because you don't have any control over your device's system launcher

Comment: okay thanks 
Maybe I should find another way.

Comment: You can close that only if you have code of the system launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your activity is on the screen then whenever a new dialog comes up, you receive a callback onWindowsFocusChanges(boolean)

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (! hasFocus) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS